# Inlined c++ code in R error.expected unqualified-id before 'while'

Tags: r, while-loop, inline, rcpp

I receive this error when running the following code aimed at producing a quicksort function. It seems to be the first while call I make that causes the problem. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)


body_sortCpp <- '

NumericVector arr(x);
int n = arr.size(); 
double tmp;
double left = arr[0];
double right = arr[n-1];
int pivot = arr[n/2];
double i = left, j = right;
while (i <= j){
while (arr[i] <= pivot)
i++;
while (arr[j] > pivot)
j--;
if (i <= j) {
tmp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = tmp;
i++;
j--;
}
}


if (left < j){
sortCpp(arr, left, j);
}
if (i < right){
sortCpp(arr, i, right);
}

return wrap( arr );
'


sortCpp <- cxxfunction( signature( x = "numeric"),
                         body = body_sortCpp,
                         include = body_sortCpp,
                         plugin = "Rcpp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `cxxfunction()` is likely wrong:

```
sortCpp <- cxxfunction( signature( x = "numeric"),
                         body = body_sortCpp,
                         include = body_sortCpp,
                         plugin = "Rcpp")
```

as you supply the code *twice*.  Remove the `include=` and you may be good to go.

Also consider a proper editor with indenting, and look into the [Rcpp Attributes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette as a superior alternative to `cxxfunction()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dirk! Awesome to get feedback from the man himself! I'm trying to incorporate recursion into the code - hence using "include". Any advice on how I could do this?

Comment: You cannot with inline as the directly-called function gets a random name.  So you need another layer of indirection -- a function calling your recursive qsort body. Or just use Rcpp Attributes and `sourceCpp()` / `cppFunction()`.